# Method [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] gets count = 0

Tags: ios5, push-notification, uilocalnotification

My app is registered for receive push notification.
I've send 3 or 4 push notification that are listed in the Notification Center; the problem is that when I try to obtain this list (inside of my application) whit this method

> [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count]

they return me 0.
But this is wrong because I can see in the NC the list of notification.

Maybe this isn't the right way to obtain the list of notification... I don't know !

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]` will give you your **local** scheduled notifications.

I'm not sure if there is an equivalent way to retrieve your push notifications since they reside on a server.

Comment: Why did you downvote my answer? You are saying that your count is 0. But you are showing the count of local notifications and NOT push notifications. And if you imagine that why do you assume that it will hold your push notifications?